# Constructor member initializer lists across members, is it safe?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have this constructor :

```
MyClass::MyClass()
 : m_foo(new Foo())
 , m_bar(new Bar(m_foo))
{
}
```

Is it safe/legit to use a member like this to initialize other members ?

Thanks

Comment: This example is not safe regardless because the second one could throw and leak the memory of the first.

Comment: @chris Depends on what `m_foo` is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yes. However, it's quite abnormal to use `new` in example code like this, which points to a different issue. `m_foo` could be a smart pointer or something, but that'd be an extra complication irrelevant to the question, so it doesn't make much sense. That was my reasoning.

Comment: @chris I'm just saying that we have no idea whether this example is safe or not.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the order in which `m_foo` and `m_bar` appear in the class definition. Since data members are initialized in order of definition, the code above is safe only if `m_foo` appears before `m_bar`.

Compilers usually warn about order mismatches between the constructor initialization list and class definition.

Comment: or if only pointer is used (store it for example) without deferencing it.

Comment: and if `m_foo` does a `delete` on destruction (exception safety)